# Printing the installation path of an external app with the winapps module

Tags: python, python-3.x

`winapps` module handles installed software.

Here's a simple example, which looks for an app with name `e-Invoicing System` and prints it's location.

```
import winapps

for app in winapps.list_installed(): # .list_installed() is a generator of InstalledApplication objects
    if app.name == "e-Invoicing System":
        print(app.install_location)
```

But this returns `None` for some reason. Why doesn't the app path "recognized"?

Comment: you should check in documentation or source code how it works - maybe it doesn't check folders but registers and it doesn't have information where it is installed.

Comment: see example on [winapps](https://github.com/rominf/winapps) GitHub. It displays `print(app)` and some apps have `install_location=None` but they still have `uninstall_string='..'` which may suggest where they are installed.